# What is the format of regular expressions in SonarQube?

Tags: regex, exception, coding-style, sonarqube, mutable

I'm trying to set the [mutable exception](http://polyweb.irisa.fr/sonar/rules/show/checkstyle%3acom.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.design.MutableExceptionCheck?layout=false) coding rule in SonarQube, but it requires a regular expression and any standard regular expression I give it results in:

```
Validation failed: Value 'regex' must be a regular expression
```

Google had no results for "regular expression sonarqube" either, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: It's a Checkstyle rule. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#MutableException. This is a regular Java expression and there supposed to be a validation of the regular expression when you click on "Update". What is your regular expression?
Could you try to set this parameter to the default value provided by Checkstyle?

Comment: That worked! Please put your comment into an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Checkstyle rule. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#MutableException. This is a regular Java expression and there is supposed to be a validation of the regular expression when you click on "Update".